# Why does Char's iterator removes element in Rust?

Tags: rust, iterator

I stumbled on something I was not expecting when using the `Chars` type. I called, the `.next()` method and found out it was mutating the original char values.

To illustrate in code and to compare with calling `next` on a vec:

```
   let mut c: Chars = "hello".chars();
   dbg!(c.next()); // prints Some("h")
   dbg!(c); // prints Chars(['e','l','l','o',])
```

As you can see, after calling `next` the `h` is gone, and the `c` value is now `'e','l','l','o'`

Whereas with vec, that is not the case:

```
   let v1 = vec![1, 2, 3];
   let mut v1_iter = v1.iter();
   dbg!(v1_iter.next()); // prints Some(1)
   dbg!(v1); // prints [1,2,3]
```

As can be seen, calling `next` does not mutate `v1` to remove the `1` element.

Why is this the case with `Chars`? Is it demonstrating a well defined characteristics for some type of iterators in rust that I am not aware of? That it iterators where iterating actually consumes and mutates the original value being iterated?

Comment: You're comparing apples and oranges here. In one case you're printing the iterator itself, while in the other you're printing the original container. If you print `v1_iter`, or if you do `let s = "hello"; let c = s.chars();` and print `s`, you'll notice that they behave the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing apples and oranges here. In one case you're printing the iterator itself, while in the other you're printing the original container. If you print `v1_iter`, or if you do `let s = "hello"; let c = s.chars();` and print `s`, you'll notice that they behave the same:

```
let s = "hello";
let mut c: Chars = s.chars();
dbg!(c.next()); // prints Some("h")
dbg!(c); // prints Chars(['e','l','l','o',])
dbg!(s); // prints "hello"

let v1 = vec![1, 2, 3];
let mut v1_iter = v1.iter();
dbg!(v1_iter.next()); // prints Some(1)
dbg!(v1_iter); // prints Iter ([ 2, 3, ],)
dbg!(v1); // prints [1,2,3]
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=eb300e599ded272d274f6e8dd50cbc14)